# Time Table in Latex

Tags: tables

Could some one guide me in making this table in Latex? I am new to programming and I couldn't go through to this because of my poor programming skills.

[image]

Edited: Could someone fix the last column in last row which shows "Cancelled"?

[image]

Here is my coding,

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|c|l|c|l|} \hline

&\multicolumn{2}{||c|}{6.15-7.15 pm}
&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{7.20-8.20 pm}
&\multicolumn{2}{|c||}{8.30-9.30 pm}\\ \hline \hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Day} &\multirow{3}{*}{Subj.} &Teacher & &Teacher &\multirow{3}{*}{Subj.}&Teacher\\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}& &Room
&\multirow{1}{*}{Subj.} &Room &  &Room \\ \hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Mon} &\multirow{3}{*}{UNIX} &Dr. Smith & &Ms. Clarke  &\multirow{3}{*}{Math.}&Mr.Mills\\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} & &Comp. Ctr
&\multirow{1}{*}{Fortran} &Hall A &  &Hall A \\ \hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Tues} &\multirow{3}{*}{LaTex} &Miss Baker & &Ms. Clarke  &\multirow{3}{*}{Math.}&Mr.Mills\\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} & &Conf. Room
&\multirow{1}{*}{Fortran} &Conf.Room &  &Hall A \\ \hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Wed} &\multirow{3}{*}{UNIX} &Dr. Smith & &Dr. Jones &\multirow{3}{*}{ComSci}&Dr.Jones\\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} & &Comp. Ctr
&\multirow{1}{*}{C} &Hall B &  &Hall B \\ \hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Fri} &\multirow{3}{*}{LaTex} &Miss Baker & &Ms. Clarke  &\multirow{3}{*}{Cancelled } & \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} & &Conf. Room &\multirow{1}{*}{C++} &Conf.Room &  &  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to TeX.SX. Not really sure typesetting this table counts as 'programming', but whatever. Yes, this is possible (though not the world's prettiest table as it is). But you should help us to help you by including your best efforts so far (i.e. an MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Even if it's just a skeleton of a document, with a preamble, a `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and maybe the environment for your table set up that would help.

Comment: You're gonna wanna look at the `multirow` package and its `\multirow` command, as well as the `\multicolumn` command

Comment: I have edited the post and have included my work whatever i have done up till now. I have only included the tabular environment.

Comment: Au101, Thanks for your suggestion. It worked. Much better than before. Can you help me fix the last column and last row which shows "Cancelled"? Also, Could you check if there is any error or better coding suggestion?

Comment: @Jack: Don't include code as images. Insert them as text in your post so we can copy-and-paste them into an editor...

Comment: @Werner I have added my code as text.

Answer (score 4):

Is it something like that  you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\newlength{\lA}\settowidth{\lA}{ComSci}
%\setlength{\lA}{2cm}
\newlength{\lB}\settowidth{\lB}{Conf. Room}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|>{\centering}m{\lA}|m{\lB}|>{\centering}m{\lA}|S{m{\lB}}|>{\centering}m{\lA}|m{\lB}|}%
    \cline{2-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{@{\,}|Sc|}{6.15-7.15 pm}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{7.20-8.20 pm}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{8.30-9.30 pm}\\
    \cline{2-7} \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Day} & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Subj.} & Teacher & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Subj.} & Teacher & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Subj.} & Teacher \\%
    \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
                                  & & Room & & Room & & Room \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Mon} & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{UNIX} & Dr. Smith & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Fortran} & Ms. Clarke & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Math.} & Mr.Mills \\ %
    \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} & & Comp. Ctr
    & & Hall A & & Hall A \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Tues} & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{LaTeX} & Miss Baker & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Fortran} & Ms. Clarke & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Math.} & Mr.Mills \\ %
    \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
                                  & & Conf. Room & & Conf.Room & & Hall A \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Wed} & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{UNIX} & Dr. Smith & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{C} & Dr. Jones & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{ComSci} & Dr.Jones \\%
    \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
                                  & & Comp. Ctr & & Hall B & & Hall B \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Fri} & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{LaTeX} & Miss Baker & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{C++} & Ms. Clarke & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{Cancelled }} \\ %
    \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
    & & Conf. Room & & Conf.Room & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]